# Spring cloud function accessing query parameters

Tags: spring-cloud-function

Is it possible to access to query parameters that are forwarded from aws apigateway to awslamdba implemented using spring cloud function. the following is my implementation.
I call this using http get request

example: http://sampledomain.com/test?param1=value

How can I retrieve param1 value in the method below

```
@Bean    
public Function<Message<String>,String> reverseString2() {      
    return value1 -> {              
          System.out.println("headers..."+value1.getHeaders());           
          value1.getHeaders().entrySet().forEach(entry -> System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " - " + entry.getValue()));             
          return "example";
    } ;
}
```

Comment: It should be in headers. Are you saying it is not? What version of s-c-function you are using?

Comment: it is pulling 3.2.x and the spring cloud version i am using is 2021.0.1 the below is my pom  <parent>  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
  <version>2.6.4</version>
  <relativePath /> 
 </parent>  <dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
   <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
    <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
    <type>pom</type>
    <scope>import</scope>
   </dependency>
  </dependencies>

Comment: Than it should be in headers. Is it not?

Comment: when i use the below I am getting the path parameters. @Bean
 public Function<APIGatewayProxyRequestEvent, String> reverseString1() {
  return value1 -> {
   System.out.println("headers..." + value1.getHeaders());
   System.out.println("paylaod..." + value1.getPathParameters());
   return "sample";
  };
 }

Comment: not sure what i am missing.. the following are the headers from my cloudwatch logs

Comment: headers...{Accept=*/*, User-Agent=PostmanRuntime/7.29.0, X-Forwarded-Proto=https, Host=sample.amazonaws.com, Accept-Encoding=gzip, deflate, br, X-Forwarded-Port=443, X-Amzn-Trace-Id=Root=1-62222c8a-57b869000c13c60c6582a823, X-Forwarded-For=71.135.203.35, aws-api-gateway=true, Postman-Token=0b9704a3-b30f-4894-9071-a4d1ba3620de, id=40f0d0a2-effe-d722-47f9-2a3c5e55657e, Content-Type=application/json, timestamp=1646406794522}

Comment: I do not see query parameters. but I notice it as part of events 2022-03-04 15:13:14.520  INFO 9 --- [           main] o.s.c.f.adapter.aws.FunctionInvoker      : Received:...     "queryStringParameters": {
        "test": "test1"
    },

Comment: If I set handler to SpringBootApiGatewayRequestHandler then I get access to querystringparameters not if I use functioninvoker. But SpringBootApiGatewayRequesthandler is deprecated.

Comment: I must be missing something as I can not reproduce it, so I need a reproducible sample as I can clearly see headers are being propagated. You can create a bare minimum sample, push it to github so we can take a look

Comment: ok sure.. I am able to get headers.. but not able to see query parameters in those headers. I notice that in aws apigateway those in differnt section(as part of event)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the Message supports the Query Parameters. You can try either of the options -

1. Change your Function to `Function<APIGatewayProxyRequestEvent, Message<String>>` and then you can access the query parameters using `apiGatewayProxyRequestEvent.getQueryStringParameters()`
2. If you want to use `Function<Message<String>, Message<String>>` , you can change the HttpMethod to POST and send the message in the Request body. `Message.getPayload()` will provide you with the content.